# How can I create a problem environment where I specify the problem number?

Tags: numbering, environments, theorems

The ams package's `\newtheorem{prob}` doesn't work here (without resetting the counter every time I want to skip a problem}. It would be nice if I could use something like

```
\begin{prob}{2-5}
    Some really smart lookin stuff
\end{prob}
```

Is there a way to do this? Additionally, I would like to specify no indent for the problem environment.

Comment: One possible solution is to use the `enumerate` environment. Using the `enumitem` package, you can reset the left indent and I think customize the format to say "Problem 1," "Problem 2," etc.

Comment: Does it need to "plug into" an existing environment?  And it is nearly always helpful to provide a complete, but minimal `.tex` file because some of the things you assume are obvious will not be obvious to others.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using a wrapper environment with optional argument. If this is used, another numbering is applied.

However, since `probleminternal` is used, the counter is increased anyway. To bypass this add `-1` to the increased counter number.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse}%

\newtheorem{probleminternal}{Problem}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{prob}{o}{%
  \IfValueT{#1}{%
    \renewcommand{\theprobleminternal}{#1}%
    \addtocounter{probleminternal}{-1}%
  }%
  \probleminternal%
}
{\endprobleminternal}

\begin{document}

\begin{prob}
Find all solutions of 

\[ x^2 - 5x + 6 = 0 \]

for $x\in\mathbb{R}$
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}[2-5]\label{myproblem}
Find all solutions of 

\[ x^4 - 13x^2 + 36 = 0 \]

for $x\in\mathbb{R}$
\end{prob}


\begin{prob}\label{myotherproblem}
Find all solutions of 

\[ x^4 - 5x^2 + 4 = 0 \]

for $x\in\mathbb{R}$
\end{prob}

Solve the problems \ref{myproblem} and \ref{myotherproblem}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, avoid the empty/blank lines before `\[...\]`. If they form part of the sentence structure, don't leave empty/blank lines.

Comment: @Werner: Yes and no -- it's a matter of personal taste rather, isn't it? I teach pupils and most of them need more white space to recognize the math content (believe me, this is the truth), so I deviate from usual textbook or article publication math style